# Plotly: how to increase width Y axis?

Tags: r, plot, plotly

I want to increase the width of the Y-axis of a `plotly` horizontal bar chart. Right now, text falls of the plot because the y axis is too narrow.

You can see the same happening on the [examples](https://plot.ly/r/horizontal-bar-charts/) page of Plotly, where the categories are simple not readable very well.

I can't find a way to increase width. Help is highly appreciated!

Example code:

```
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(x = c(20, 14, 23), 
  y = c('long string which is not readable', 
    'orangutans (not readable)', 
    'monkeys'), 
  type = 'bar', 
  orientation = 'h')
```

Comment: It should be possible, as it is in their UI here: https://help.plot.ly/axes/#step-8-axis-width

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plotly hid this quite well... You can change this in the layout of the xaxis, under domain.

The following will work:

```
ax <- list(
        domain = list(0.2, 1)
      )
p <- plot_ly(x = c(20, 14, 23), 
  y = c('long string which is not readable', 
    'orangutans (not readable)', 
    'monkeys'), 
  type = 'bar', 
  orientation = 'h') %>%
layout(xaxis = ax)
```

General tip: Plotly has an [online editor](https://plot.ly/create/), where you can export a JSON object, which contains all the settings. Then, searching through that object might help the find the right settings.